# Ionic 5 file picker issue

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I'm using ionic 5

these are the versions of the plugins I'm using:

```
  "@ionic-native/camera": "5.3.0",
  "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "5.2.0",
  "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "9.0.1",
  "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
  "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
  "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.2",
  "community-cordova-plugin-file-opener": "^3.1.0",
  "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
  "cordova-plugin-camera-preview": "0.9.0",
```

with the new android api I had to set my cdvTargetSdkVersion to 33 in the Gradle properties to support android 11+

The plugin is installed following the readme guidelines. It compiles with no issues and it's working with iOS when I try to upload an image for the user's profile in the app.

The problem comes when I try to do the same on Android, it shows a log in console that says `Error:  20` when I try to call the camera plugin `this.camera.pickFile(CameraSourceType.GALERY, CameraMediaType.ALL)`

```js
pickFile(sourceType, mediaType): Observable<string> {
    let cameraOptions = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit: false,
      mediaType: 0,
      targetWidth: 512,
      targetHeight: 512
    };

    return from(this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res;
      })
    );
  }
```

I have checked the android permissions are set correctly in the android manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Is there anything I may be missing?